# Spring plan for Zuul 2

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I've heard that Zuul 2 is released. Are there any plan of updating Spring for it? I can't wait.

I applied Spring cloud to build a microservice system and think they are awesome. So, Zuul 2 makes me feel excited.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell Zuul 2 has [not been released](http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/09/zuul-2-netflix-journey-to-asynchronous.html).

> We are in the process of releasing Zuul 2 as open source. Once it is
>   released...

That being said, given enough lead time, we plan on integrating zuul 2 in the beginning of 2017.

Comment: Great to hear that. 2017 coming soon.

Comment: It is 2017 now.How the plan going?

Comment: zuul 2 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Is zuul 2 any closer yet?

Comment: I have no insight into zuul 2

Comment: Zuul2 has been released just a few days ago: 
https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/open-sourcing-zuul-2-82ea476cb2b3

Still not sure about the Spring integration.

Comment: There will not be

Comment: curious as to why there will not be an spring integration.  I assume that you evaluated Zulu 2 and decided that spring cloud gateway answers all the questions?

Answer (score 3):

There's now `spring-cloud-gateway`. Which is Spring's replacement for Zuul 1.

https://spring.io/blog/2017/07/06/spring-cloud-finchley-m1-is-available

*"Spring Cloud Gateway is a new API Gateway based on Spring 5, Boot 2 and Project Reactor. It is viewed as a replacement for Zuul 1."*

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway

Comment: Great news! I will study it. I just using Spring 4, Boot 1.x so there might be much things to migrate my current projects.

Comment: I see that it's built on project reactor. Is it non-blocking?

Comment: my opinion: spring-cloud-gateway is too complex for a stateless gateway