# How we can integrate Springboot 2.x with Zuul 2

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

We have a springboot application which is currently having gateway as Zuul 1. Our application is running in Springboot 2.0.0.M2. We are trying to upgrade our Zuul gateway to Zuul 2. We created a springboot application with Zuul 2 dependency and added webflux dependency to get Netty server. 
     The server starts fine, but we are still unclear that how the springboot application will understand that this is a gateway and filters needs to be executed. Although we have created Routes filter, but the same is not getting invoked.

Thanks in advance,
Ron

Comment: Good question, and from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878973/spring-plan-for-zuul-2) it seems that Spring Cloud Gateway is Spring's intended replacement for Zuul 1.  Not sure about integration with Zuul 2.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was under an impression that if Zuul2 dependency been added to the Springboot app, then it might start recognizing as a gateway. But it didn't and not executing the filters which I have added. Just to make sure that I am not doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

if you go through the video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wocKqF15B8" at 18:00 from spring developers. They clearly stated that zuul2 is not going to be supported by the spring ecosystem. Also, the replacement of zuul2 (non-blocking calls) is a spring cloud gateway which is also non-blocking calls.