# Springboot zuul2 integration

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Is anyone implemented working on the springboot and zuul2(Netty based implementation)?
I would like to upgrade my current implementation from zuul (1.X) using spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be supported as of now.

Ref : https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/568

and
[Spring plan for Zuul 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878973/spring-plan-for-zuul-2)